# how to handle "<" and ">" in regex in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have string in XML, `<italic>a</italic>` and I am using `xsl:analyze-string` to extract all italic words with this pattern: `"<italic>a</italic>"`. I know I can use template match on italic but the requirement here is to match it using regex. I am trying to write the expression like this, `(<italic>)[a-z]+</italic>`, but the XSLT processor is throwing an error on the opening `<` tag.

Any idea how to handle opening and closing tags in regex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/338803

Comment: Is `<italic>a</italic>` in CDATA or otherwise escaped (`&lt;`/`&gt;`)? Are you sure the processor sees it as a string?

Comment: I tried converting into (\&lt;)(italic)(\&gt;))[a-z+](\&lt;)(italic)(\/)(\&gt;)) but same result... xslt throwing error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<italic>a</italic>` is an ordinary xml element, if you are using saxon xslt processor  then use an extensions function net.sf.saxon.serialize to serialize the xml and then apply regular expression. It works great.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what your XML source looks like, but if `<italic>a</italic>` is an ordinary XML element, then you can't match the lexical form of the element using regular expressions. That's because *the input to XSLT is a tree of nodes, not a string of lexical XML markup*. That concept is absolutely crucial to understanding how XSLT works.

Comment: <italic>a</italic> is an ordinary xml element not a string and I found a way in saxon xslt processor by using net.sf.saxon.serialize function to serialize the xml and then apply regular expression. It works greate.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `<italic>a</italic>` is an actual string, you can use `&lt;` for the < character. The greater-than (>) does not need to be escaped.

Example:

**Sample XML Input**

```
<test><![CDATA[<italic>a</italic>]]></test>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="test" regex="&lt;italic>([^&lt;]+)&lt;/italic>">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <results>
          <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
        </results>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output:**

```
<results>a</results>
```

Comment: The code might be better to read if you put the pattern in a CDATA itself with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="re" as="xs:string"><![CDATA[<italic>([^<])</italic>]]></xsl:variable>`, then use that with `<xsl:analyze-string select="test" regex="{$re}">`

Comment: I agree with DevNull, but there is a slight error in your regex. IMHO  the correct regex is:

regex="&lt;italic>([^&lt;]+)&lt;/italic>"

The extra plus is because the captured mark-up (if I have understood correctly) can be more than one character. The question specifies "italic words" which implies multiple characters

Comment: unfortunetly it's not a string, it's an actual element. I found a way in saxon xslt processor by using net.sf.saxon.serialize function to serialize the xml and then apply regular expression.