# RegEx to replace empty <P> tags XSLT 2.0?

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, removing-whitespace

I currently have a XSLT 2.0 Stylesheet that I am trying to remove empty P Tags from the output. I have tried the following RegEx with no success:

```
replace($string,"&lt;p&gt;[\s{2,}]*&lt;/p&gt;","")
```

The output from the Stylesheet at the moment looks like below:

```
<p>Some Text!</p>
<p></p>
<p>Some Text!</p>
<p> </p>
<p>  </p>
<p>Some Text!</p>
```

From this I want the output to strip the P tags that have just 1 or more spaces within them, so it would look like this:

```
<p>Some Text!</p>
<p>Some Text!</p>
<p>Some Text!</p>
```

Thanks

:-)

Comment: Take a look at this site http://dh.obdurodon.org/regex.html

Comment: I would use that but I cant as I am no longer looking at a node in the xml file as the data has already gone through many conversions and currently resides in a Variable. Thanks :-)

Comment: also looked at <([^</>"=]+?)>(\s*?)</(.+?)> but not sure what equivalent XSLT RegEx would be.

Comment: I have no knowledge in XSLT but according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9979684/1113272 the ">" doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Yes I know how to deal with tage as a P tag would be &lt;p&gt; :-)

Comment: Why use regex? Change the xslt so that it doesn't output them!

Comment: Someone clearly needs a refresher: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I do understand how this works and the solution I put in place seemed to work when debugging however did not work when running normally which is strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using next regular expression: `/<p>(|\s+)<\/p>/`

**Explanation:**

```
<p>       # Match <p>
(         # Try to match...
  |\s+    #   nothing or the space character any number of times
)         # ...match end
<\/p>     # Match </p>
```

You can see it in action by the link http://regexr.com?31f6a (be sure to switch to 'Replace' mode and set replacement text to nothing).

**Update**

Actually, the `(|\s)` expression and `\s*` does the same thing (Thanks to Rawling), so you can write the main expression as `/<p>\s*<\/p>/`.

Comment: You know you can use \s* to match "the space character zero or more times"?

Comment: @Rawling Mmmm... Thanks for nice experience ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would write an XSLT stylesheet that processes the result of the first one, you only need two templates i.e.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course an alternative would be to rewrite the original stylesheet to not produce the empty `p` elements at all but for that we need to see details of the XML input and the XSLT you have.